# set of compositions where each part is restricted based on its position

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I am trying to find a generating function for the set of compositions (say $S$) of any length with a unique restriction on it. ($S$ should also include the empty composition $\epsilon$).

The restriction is for any $c = (c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_k)$ in the set, each part $c_i$ must be congruent to $i \text{ mod } 2$.

**edit**:
If trying to find a generating function for the unrestricted set of compositions, via the string lemma, we get
$$
g(x) = \frac{1}{1 - \sum_{n \geq 1} x^n} = \frac{1-x}{1-2x}.
$$
using the generating function for the set of all positive integers.

Comment: Hi Trevor. Your post is rather brief; it seems to be only a statement of a problem. Can you click "Edit" above and tell us what you've tried already? Also, it is suggested that you review this: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959

Comment: If you are attempting this problem, you must have already seen/done the simpler problem of finding the generating function the set of compositions, unrestricted. It would be easiest to show you how to solve the restricted problem in analogy with the unrestricted one, so can you include in your post the proof that the unrestricted g.f. is $(1-x)/(1-2x)$?

Comment: @MikeEarnest done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

As you mentioned in your post, an unrestricted composition can be described as an ordered sequence of "objects," where there is one object of each positive integer weight. Each object therefore has generating function $(x+x^2+x^3+\dots)$, so sequences of them have g.f.
$$
\frac1{1-(x+x^2+\dots)}=\frac{1-x}{1-2x}
$$
We can do something almost as easy with these odd-even compositions. To make things easier, let us first find the g.f. for odd-even composition $(c_1,\dots,c_{k})$ where $k$ is even. The composition is a sequence of $k/2$ pairs of integers $(d,e)$, where $d$ is odd and $e$ is even. The g.f. for $d$ is $(x+x^3+x^5+\dots)$ (one for each odd natural number), and the g.f. for $e$ is $(x^2+x^4+x^6+\dots)$ (similar). What is the g.f. for the ordered pair $(d,e)$? That is, for picking $d$ *and* $e$ together?

Once you have the g.f. $F(x)$ for pairs of (odd, even) integers, the g.f. for compositions of even length is $\frac{1}{1-F(x)}$. You then need to do something similar to find the g.f. for sequences of odd length, and than add that to $\frac1{1-F(x)}$. The odd g.f. is just a little trickier; the idea is that an odd composition is a sequence of (odd, even) pairs, followed by an odd integer.

Comment: would the generating function for the ordered pair $(d, e)$ just be g.f. for $d$ multiplied by $e$?

Comment: @trevor.yao That's right!

Comment: would the odd g.f. then be $F(x)$ multiplied by the g.f. for an odd number?

Comment: Yes, in order to add on an odd number to the end, just multiply by $(x+x^3+\dots)$. [I like the aesthetics of the phrase "add on an odd"] $\tag{*}$ I think you have all the pieces now; if you want me to check your answer, feel free to edit it into your question post.

Comment: why wouldnt we multiply $\frac{1}{1-F(x)}$ by $(x+x^3+\ldots)$?

Comment: Oops, you're right, you should multiply $\frac1{1-F(x)}$ by $(x+x^3+\dots)$.